# Received hat for posting on the 30th....on the 29th

Tags: bug

Oops, I accidentally posted tomorrow.

[image]

Even by stackoverflow's UTC timezone standards it is still the 29th.
[image]
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the 30th somewhere in the world.

From [This meta.Stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer) :

> Unless the requirement mentions a specific timezone, hats that are date-based are often awarded for 14 hours before and 12 hours after the specified date in UTC, to accommodate people everywhere in the world. This means you can earn such a hat even though for you it's not even that day yet.

Comment: Ah I knew there had to be a post about it somewhere. Seems like an odd way to go about accommodating everyone but makes sense.